# Can a full page widget be created using Google Chrome Extension

Tags: browser, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, widget

I am thinking of writing an extension for Google Chrome which needs to be its own independent widget occupying a full page of its own. Something like an extension for showing all the Twitter updates. This extension does not have anything to do with the current page on which the user is present. It is more like a widget which exists on its own. I know that a popup page can be written which pops out when the user clicks on the extension icon. But not sure how to write an extension which opens a new tab.

Thanks,
gg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to make a [packaged app](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/apps.html). It is similar to a Chrome extension but it uses a full tab instead of just a popup.